# Read into std::string using scanf

Tags: c++, c, string

As the title said, I'm curious if there is a way to read a C++ string with scanf.

I know that I can read each char and insert it in the deserved string, but I'd want something like:

```
string a;
scanf("%SOMETHING", &a);
```

`gets()` also doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just curious, why can't you use cin or getline?

Comment: On some compilers using streams take a lot of time... and I'm coding for a compiler like that here..

Comment: @Vlad: you should start your program with `std::ios_base::syc_with_stdio(false);` if reading from standard input is too slow.

Comment: @DietmarKühl You meant std::ios_base::sy**n**c_with_stdio(false);, right? I second your opinion, often this makes an impressive difference.

Comment: but sometimes you may just want formatted reading with as little overhead as possible.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no situation under which `gets()` is to be used! It is **always** wrong to use `gets()` and it is removed from C11 and being removed from C++14.

`scanf()` doens't support any C++ classes. However, you can store the result from `scanf()` into a `std::string`:

> *Editor's note: The following code is wrong, as explained in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165954/read-c-string-with-scanf#comment61590562_20166048). See the answers by [Patato](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165954/read-c-string-with-scanf#20166003), [tom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165954/read-c-string-with-scanf#60437601), and [Daniel Trugman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165954/read-c-string-with-scanf#62504517) for correct approaches.*

```
std::string str(100, ' ');
if (1 == scanf("%*s", &str[0], str.size())) {
    // ...
}
```

I'm not entirely sure about the way to specify that buffer length in `scanf()` and in which order the parameters go (there is a chance that the parameters `&str[0]` and `str.size()` need to be reversed and I may be missing a `.` in the format string). Note that the resulting `std::string` will contain a terminating null character and it won't have changed its size.

Of course, I would just use `if (std::cin >> str) { ... }` but that's a different question.

Comment: Are you sure your code is compiling? I get compilation error using both C++98 and C++11

Comment: @Vlad: I'd think the code should compile assuming you included `<string>` and `<stdio.h>` and sits within a function, of course. What error messages do you get?

Comment: @Vlad: OK, I see: seems `std::string` doesn't declare a constructor taking just a size. Using `std::string str(100, ' ');` fixes this problem.

Comment: At compile time one cannot safely specify 100, or any other finite number, to limit the length of what scanf will write into `%*s`.  +Patato's answer is safer.  Google "buffer overflow".

Comment: It should be `scanf("%99s", &str[0]))`, as `scanf()` does not allow to specify the field width during run-time using the `*`, as `printf()` does. Also `scanf()` suffixes what had been read in with the `0`-terminator, so one needs to read in one few than `str`'s size.

Comment: For `scanf`, the `*` *supresses* assignment, it does not mean to take the next argument as the field width.

Comment: "*I'm not entirely sure about the way to specify that buffer lenght in scanf() and in which order the parameters go*" - Easy: You can't do it at all. `scanf` does not support length parameters. This code does not work.

Answer (score 39):

this can work

```
char tmp[101];
scanf("%100s", tmp);
string a = tmp;
```

Comment: I didn't know that I can initialize a C++ string with a char[] .. thanks a lot! :)

Comment: It can work. It can also have undefined behavior because the contents of `tmp` may be uninitialized here. Never use `scanf` without checking its return value.

Comment: But it is chopping off the first character of string in my case. I have done something like this :-
``` string x;
 scanf("%s", &x);```

Answer (score 5):

### Problem explained:

You CAN populate the underlying buffer of an `std::string` using `scanf`, but(!) the managed `std::string` object will NOT be aware of the change.

```
const char *line="Daniel 1337"; // The line we're gonna parse

std::string token;
token.reserve(64); // You should always make sure the buffer is big enough

sscanf(line, "%s %*u", token.data());
std::cout << "Managed string: '" << token
          << " (size = " << token.size() << ")" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Underlying buffer: " << token.data()
          << " (size = " << strlen(token.data()) << ")" << std::endl;
```

Outputs:

```
Managed string:  (size = 0)
Underlying buffer: Daniel (size = 6)
```

So, what happened here?
**The object `std::string` is not aware of changes not performed through the exported, official, API.**

When we write to the object through the underlying buffer, the data changes, but the string object is not aware of that.

If we were to replace the original call: `token.reseve(64)` with `token.resize(64)`, a call that changes the size of the managed string, the results would've been different:

```
const char *line="Daniel 1337"; // The line we're gonna parse

std::string token;
token.resize(64); // You should always make sure the buffer is big enough

sscanf(line, "%s %*u", token.data());
std::cout << "Managed string: " << token
          << " (size = " << token.size() << ")" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Underlying buffer: " << token.data()
          << " (size = " << strlen(token.data()) << ")" << std::endl;
```

Outputs:

```
Managed string: Daniel (size = 64)
Underlying buffer: Daniel (size = 6)
```

Once again, the result is sub-optimal. The output is correct, but the size isn't.

### Solution:

If you really want to make do this, follow these steps:

1. Call `resize` to make sure your buffer is big enough. Use a `#define` for the maximal length (see step 2 to understand why):

```
std::string buffer;
buffer.resize(MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH);
```

2. Use `scanf` while limiting the size of the scanned string using "width modifiers" and check the return value (return value is the number of tokens scanned):

```
#define XSTR(__x) STR(__x)
#define STR(__x) #x
...
int rv = scanf("%" XSTR(MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH) "s", &buffer[0]);
```

3. Reset the managed string size to the actual size in a safe manner:

```
buffer.resize(strnlen(buffer.data(), MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH));
```

Comment: Good catch, I've fixed this bug in my answer. Some small issues in your answer: concatenation of side-by-side string literals doesn't work with integers, so `"%" MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH "s"` is a syntax error. This can be fixed using [stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html): write `#define STR0(x) #x` and `#define STR(x) STR0(x)` then use `"%" STR(MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH) "s"`. Also, the return type of string::data() is `const char*` which shouldn't be modified, so use `&buffer[0]` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The below snippet works

```
string s(100, '\0');
scanf("%s", s.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct an std::string of an appropriate size and read into its underlying character storage:

```
std::string str(100, ' ');
scanf("%100s", &str[0]);
str.resize(strlen(str.c_str()));
```

The call to str.resize() is critical, otherwise the length of the std::string object will not be updated. Thanks to [Daniel Trugman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165954/read-c-string-with-scanf#62504517) for pointing this out.

<sup>(There is no off-by-one error with the size reserved for the string versus the width passed to `scanf`, because since C++11 it is guaranteed that the character data of std::string is followed by a null terminator so there is room for size+1 characters.)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here a version without limit of length (in case of the length of the input is unknown).

```
std::string read_string() {
  std::string s; unsigned int uc; int c;
  // ASCII code of space is 32, and all code less or equal than 32 are invisible.
  // For EOF, a negative, will be large than 32 after unsigned conversion
  while ((uc = (unsigned int)getchar()) <= 32u);
  if (uc < 256u) s.push_back((char)uc);
  while ((c = getchar()) > 32) s.push_back((char)c);
  return s;
}
```

For performance consideration, `getchar` is definitely faster than `scanf`, and [std::string::reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/reserve/) could pre-allocate buffers to prevent frequent reallocation.

Answer (score 0):

```
int n=15; // you are going to scan no more than n symbols
std::string str(n+1); //you can't scan more than string contains minus 1
scanf("%s",str.begin()); // scanf only changes content of string like it's array
str=str.c_str() //make string normal, you'll have lots of problems without this string
```