# How to use scanf and printf for string in C language

Tags: c, c++11

I don't want to declare character array. I want to declare string. And take input and show output of that string using scanf and printf. I have tried to do it this way that's shown below but it doesn't work properly. How to do it in proper way?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;

    scanf("%s", str.c_str());
    printf("%s", str.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

[When I take input using this code, output shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q588g.png)

Comment: C or C++? C does not have strings - only nul terminated char arrays. So you *must* use a character array.

Comment: Yes, but _why_?

Comment: _it doesn't work properly_. --> Can you elaborate it a bit?

Comment: `str.c_str()` is read-only. And not allocated/empty... UB. use `std::cin` instead. `std::string` supports it natively

Comment: You are not supposed to mix C and C++ like that. It's basically impossible to make the `scanf` line correct because it reads an arbitrary amount of data into a buffer, so you need an arbitrarily big buffer which means you must make the buffer bigger while reading. `scanf` doesn't do that. `std::cin` does so you can do `std::cin >> str;`. You should try to use the tools that do exactly what you want instead of hacking on tools that are made for a different purpose.

Comment: Didn't you get at least a warning for the `scanf`?

Comment: `str.c_str()` returns a `const char *` for a reason.

Comment: @MichaelWalz no i didnt get any warning

Comment: @H.S. I have just added a photo of my output.

Comment: @AsifMohammad if you use gcc you can compile with the `-Wall` flag.

Comment: @AsifMohammad: check [read-c-string-with-scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165954/read-c-string-with-scanf)

Comment: Scanf is inherently dangerous because it doesn't limit the size of string that it will fetch. You should at least specify a max width in your %s. 
When I really do need to go via scanf, or absolutely must interface with other c-style file handles, or system file handles, then I end up using a std::vector<char>, (though you can reserve(0 and data() a string in c++17), but you still need to reserve() the max string size you can accept.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write in a zone which is read only e.g. str.c_str().
What you want to do is either :

```
 std::cin >> str;
```

or if for a specific reason you have to use scanf. Since C++17 you can do :

```
  str.data()
```

Which returns a modifiable memory zone.

Edit : as @nwp said, you have to call str.resize(size) to because the size of the string is 0 before that.

Comment: Modifiable yes, but with size 0, so not very useful. You would need to call `str.resize(some_magic_number);` first.

Comment: @nwp True, I don't see the point of using scanf here so I omitted that detail. Thanks I'll edit to match your comment