# scanf function for strings

Tags: c++, scanf

The problem is simple, the code below does not work. it says `Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)`. Removing ampersand does not change anything.

```
int main(){
    string x;
    scanf("%s",&x);
    cout << x;
}
```

Comment: Use c-like strings or, **better**, use `cin` instead.

Comment: I know about `cin`, but now want to figure out what is wrong with that. I've noticed that it is faster than `cin`, thus better for competitive programming.

Comment: How can I use c-like strings?

Comment: Did you try `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio (false);`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406935/reading-a-string-with-scanf

Comment: This does not fix it.

Comment: What doesn't fix what?

Comment: I mean, it does not change anything.

Comment: Why did you think it would work? Which reference material or piece of documentation told you that it would work? Who explained that you could overwrite a `std::string` using a C library function? They were wrong.

Comment: Not syncing with C stdio is like releasing the handbrake on C++ IO. If you don't need this synchronization, that is. Another advise is to turn on warnings when compiling. Most compilers would have told you that the code is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read C++ string with scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165954/read-c-string-with-scanf)

Comment: Consider accepting an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf()` with the `%s` format specifier reads bytes into a *preallocated* character array (`char[]`), to which you pass a pointer.

Your `s` is not a character array. It is a `std::string`, a complex object.

A `std::string*` is not in any way the same as a `char*`. Your code overwrites the memory of parts of a complex object in unpredictable ways, so you end up with a crash.

Your compiler should have warned about this, since it knows that a `char*` is not a `std::string*`, and because compilers are clever and can detect mistakes like this despite the type-unsafe nature of C library functions.

Even if this were valid via some magic compatibility layer, the `string` is empty.

Use I/O streams instead.

Comment: "*Unfortunately, the type-unsafe nature of C library functions such as this means that your compiler couldn't detect and reject the mismatch.*" - actually, several modern C++ compilers CAN validate and reject this at compile time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau truth

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass complex objects through the ... operator of printf/scanf. Many compilers print a warning for that.

`scanf` requires a pointer of type `char*` pointing to sufficient storage for an argument of `%s`. std::string is something completely different.

In C++ the iostream operators are intended for text input and output.

```
cin >> x;
```

will do the job.

You should not use `scanf` in C++. There are many pitfalls, you found one of them.

Another pitfall: `%s` at scanf is almost always undefined behavior unless you you really ensure that the source stream can only contain strings of limited size. In this case a buffer of `char buffer[size];` is the right target.
In any other case you should at least restrict the size of the string to scan. E.g. use `%20s` and of course a matching char buffer, `char buffer[21];`in this case. Note the size +1.

Comment: You are right, but the OP wrote that he also tried without `&`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `cin`. But if you want to use `scanf()` for whatever reason and still manipulate your strings with `std::string`, then you can read the C-string and use it to initialize your C++ string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    char c_str[80];

    scanf("%s", c_str);
    string str(c_str);

    cout << str << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use strings, use `cin` (or `getline`).

```
string s;
cin>>s;   //s is now read
```

If you want to use `scanf`, you want to have a char array (and don't use `&`):

```
char text[30];
scanf("%s", text); //text is now read
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `char[]` instead of `string`

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char tmp[101];
  scanf("%100s", tmp);
  cout << tmp;
}
```