# input std string in c++ with scanf

Tags: c++

Why the result of my code is not true. Is it because scanf function?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s, t;
    scanf("%s", s.c_str());
    scanf("%s", t.c_str());
    int a = s.find(t);
    while(a > -1){
        s = s.erase(a, t.length());
        a = s.find(t);
    }
    printf("%s", s.c_str());
}
```

Comment: That should give you compile warnings to start with. `c_str` returns a `const char*` while `%s` expects a non-`const` pointer

Comment: And you simply cannot directly write to a `std::string` via C IO functions

Comment: There is no reason to assume that strings `s` and `t` have buffers large enough to take the scanned string.

Comment: why do you want to do this instead of the perfectly legal and working C++ `std::cin >> s >> t;` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read into std::string using scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165954/read-into-stdstring-using-scanf)

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` will simply write to any buffer you give it. It doesn't know that the buffer belongs to a `std::string`, nor does it know how large the buffer is. Also you are writing to a `const char*` - that points to a readonly buffer of unknown size. Your code has undefined behaviour.

Yes, it is possible to directly write to the internal buffer of a `std::string` using [`std::string::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data). But when you do this, you need to make sure the buffer is large enough using [`resize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) or [constructor #2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

```cpp
int main(){
    string s(4096, '\0');
    scanf("%s", s.data());
    ...
}
```

You end up with the same problem as if you were using a plain `char[]`.

The C++-way `std::cin >> s;` or `std::getline(std::cin, s)` would be much easier and safer.

Comment: Note, also, that if `scanf` reads, for example, only one character, `s.size()` is still 4096. +1.

Comment: Okay thank you for the answer and your suggestion churill and pete becker. I decide to use cin because that is still not work